# How To edit some packages stored in msdb

Tags: sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2005

im a newbie with sql-server 2005. i build some packages which import some flatfiles into  tables, each file goes into his table. Now there is a change in the structure of one file.

Now i am too stupid to change this package which is stored on the server in msdb. Please be kind and explain the steps to get the package in visual studio for editing, thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about an Integration Services package, as these are the only "packages" that get deployed to the MSDB database :)

To edit a package that's been deployed to MSDB, you'll need to connect to the Integration Services instance on the server, locate the package, and export it as a `.dtsx` package.

Then you should be able to open it in Visual Studio, edit it, and redeploy if necessary.

Comment: Sounds like the way i did it some months ago. i'm not familiar with that sql-2005 thing, but isn't it possible to manage them like sql-2000? At my point of view it's an overkill to do something like exporte as *.dtsx an reimport it - is that the truth?
I'm very confused.

Comment: SQL 2000 used something called DTS (Data Transformation Services) to do what Integration Services does. Integration Services allows you to edit the source of the files (allowing e.g. source-code control), run the files directly without deploying, deploy to multiple servers, etc., all of which DTS made quite hard. The cost, of course, is that you have to use Visual Studio to edit the packages, where in SQL 2000 it was all done in Enterprise Manager :)

Comment: You are right, but me as a database passionate everything in the filesystem is evil...

Answer (score 0):

By package, I assume you mean table or similar.

The easiest thing you can do for SQL 2005 is download [SQL Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en) for free and then login,and you can delete, modify or do anything with any databases currently loaded in your SQL instance.

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault; i mentioned no table. As i'm not so familiar with that ssis-thing...

Comment: sorry, my fault, I missed the term package! still, download Management Studio Express - as per your comment on Jeremy's answer, Management Studio Express is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Management Studio Express has _no_ features that allow modification of SSIS packages. Sorry, your answer has no relevance to his problem :)